# 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions - Error while integrating Kendo Grid with Angular 5

Tags: kendo-ui, angular5

I have purchased the script of a Kendo Ui Grid, and I'm integrating it with Angular 5. However, when I'm trying to call the **read** method, its not getting getting invoked; and the following exception is showing -
[image]